# Plotting a heat map of Pennsylvania counties in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with Pennsylvania counties(67) and the frequency of each county. Now, I want to create a heat map with the frequencies. I am using the map library of R:

```
require(maps)
m<-map("county","Pennsylvania")
```

This returns a map like this:

[image]

Using this [dataset](https://plcbplus.pa.gov/pub/LicenseExportWithSecondaries.aspx), I have created a summary table of the number of points per counties. The output of `dput(Frequency)` is as follows:

```
Frequency <- structure(list(County_join = c("adams", "allegheny", "armstrong", 
"beaver", "bedford", "berks", "blair", "bradford", "bucks", "butler", 
"cambria", "cameron", "carbon", "centre", "chester", "clarion", 
"clearfield", "clinton", "columbia", "crawford", "cumberland", 
"dauphin", "delaware", "elk", "erie", "fayette", "forest", "franklin", 
"fulton", "greene", "huntingdon", "indiana", "jefferson", "juniata", 
"lackawanna", "lancaster", "lawrence", "lebanon", "lehigh", "luzerne", 
"lycoming", "mckean", "mercer", "mifflin", "monroe", "montgomery", 
"montour", "northampton", "northumberland", "perry", "philadelphia", 
"pike", "potter", "schuylkill", "snyder", "somerset", "sullivan", 
"susquehanna", "tioga", "union", "venango", "warren", "washington", 
"wayne", "westmoreland", "wyoming", "york", NA), Frequencies = c(312L, 
5367L, 263L, 537L, 136L, 1176L, 431L, 203L, 1475L, 541L, 626L, 
31L, 322L, 398L, 984L, 174L, 327L, 146L, 245L, 373L, 500L, 954L, 
1257L, 174L, 1008L, 554L, 46L, 230L, 24L, 104L, 102L, 272L, 177L, 
38L, 1159L, 1040L, 219L, 292L, 933L, 1701L, 458L, 211L, 399L, 
126L, 592L, 1890L, 72L, 868L, 330L, 94L, 5300L, 212L, 92L, 724L, 
91L, 311L, 48L, 172L, 147L, 87L, 125L, 153L, 795L, 269L, 1388L, 
118L, 872L, 1590L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-68L))
```

How do I convert this to colored choropleth heat map of frequencies?

Comment: What dataset you using?

Comment: It's a csv file with license information of counties in Pennsylvania. I want to create a heat map showing the counties with most licenses and least ones

Comment: dput(df) your data sample, where df is your data

Comment: Tried. But how does it help?

Comment: You did not provide any data so how can we know what frequency variable you want to plot on this map. You should provide some data anyway.

Comment: https://plcbplus.pa.gov/pub/LicenseExportWithSecondaries.aspx this is a dataset and from this I have created a separate table with counties and frequencies.

Comment: @Ankur, I have edited the question to show how you should include the data directly within the question, not link to an external dataset. The aim is to make it as easy as possible for others to help you. Hope that helps to see what to do for the future :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readr)
library(maps)
LicenseListWithSecondaries <- read_csv("C:/Users/..../Downloads/LicenseListWithSecondaries.csv")

License_final <- LicenseListWithSecondaries %>% 
                        filter(Status == 'Active') %>% 
                        mutate(County_join = tolower(str_remove_all(County, " County"))) %>% 
                        group_by(County_join) %>% summarise(Frequencies = n())

#m <- map("county","Pennsylvania")

Pennsylvania <- map_data("county","Pennsylvania")

Pennsylvania_final <- inner_join(Pennsylvania, License_final,by=c('subregion' = 'County_join'))

pen_base <- ggplot(data = Pennsylvania_final, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = subregion)) + 
coord_fixed(1.3) + 
geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = "gray")

ditch_the_axes <- theme(
axis.text = element_blank(),
axis.line = element_blank(),
axis.ticks = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_blank(),
panel.grid = element_blank(),
axis.title = element_blank()
)

pen_base + 
geom_polygon(aes(fill = Frequencies), color = "white") +
geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA) +
theme_bw() +
ditch_the_axes +
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(7)),
               breaks = c(2, 4, 10, 100, 1000, 10000),
               trans = "log10")
```

[image]

You can check [here](http://eriqande.github.io/rep-res-web/lectures/making-maps-with-R.html) for more information. I hope it helps.

Comment: WOW! Great. It helps alot.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(maps)
require(sf)
require(dplyr)

# load freq data
df <- read.csv("D:/GoogleDrive/stack/df.csv", sep = ",")

# select administrative divisions with 5 digits code i.e. county level
df_five = df %>% filter(grepl(".*\\b(\\d{5})\\b.*", LID)) %>% 
                mutate(NAME = gsub(" County", "", County)) %>% 
                select(-County)

# find county frequencies
freq <- df_five %>% 
  group_by( NAME) %>% 
  summarise(n = length(NAME)) %>% 
  arrange(-n) %>% 
  filter(NAME != "")

# join county info to count frequency
res <- freq %>% left_join(df_five %>% select(LID, NAME), by="NAME")

# define color buckets
colors = c("#F1EEF6", "#D4B9DA", "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#DD1C77", "#980043", "#4c0021")
res$colorBuckets <- as.numeric(cut(res$n, c(0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3500)))
leg.txt <- c("< 500", "500-1000", "1000-1500", "1500-2000", "2000-2500", "2500-3500")

# draw map
map("county", "Pennsylvania", col = colors, fill = TRUE, resolution = 0,
    lty = 0, projection = "polyconic")
map("state", col = "white", fill = FALSE, add = TRUE, lty = 1, lwd = 0.2,
    projection="polyconic")
legend("topright", leg.txt, horiz = TRUE, fill = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Great. Helps alot!